# Random generated number result doesn't match with the user input

Tags: c++

1. I'm having a problem with the random generated number result not matching with the user input and it only outputs the first statements instead of falling to else if the user guessed wrong.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <ctime>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;


   int main()
   {

       int bank = 10;
       int heads = 0;
       int tails = 1;
       char response;
       string headsTails;
       int coinToss = rand() % 2;
       srand(static_cast<int>(time(0)));


       cout << "Welcome to the coin flip game. It cost a dollar to play. " <<  endl;
       cout << "If you guess correctly you will win $2.00 dollars " << endl;
       cout << "Do you want to play? (Y/N) " << endl;
       cin >> response;


       while (toupper(response) == 'Y')
       {
           cout << "Your bank is $" << bank << " dollars." << endl;
           cout << "Enter head or tails (H/T)" << endl;
           cin >> response;

           coinToss = rand() % 2;
           headsTails = coinToss ? "Heads" : "Tails";

           if (coinToss == heads || coinToss == tails)
           {
               cout << "Winner! The coin flip came up " << headsTails << endl;
               cout << "Would you like to play again? (Y/N) " << endl;
               cin >> response;
               bank += 2;
           }
           else
           {
               cout << "Sorry, you lose. The coin flip came up " << headsTails << 
   endl;
               cout << "Would you like to play again? (Y/N) " << endl;
               cin >> response;
               bank -= 1;
           }

       }
       cout << "Thanks for playing! Your bank is " << bank << endl;
       cout << "Please come again! " << endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: If you wanted to compare the result of the coin toss to the user input, you should actually do that. You're ignoring the user input now. It's not some mysterious thing that the code is doing, you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (coinToss == heads || coinToss == tails)
```

That condition is wrong, it will always evaluate to true since you set `coinToss` to 0 or 1 yourself.

You have to use the `response` variable you ask of the user, something like:

```
int guess = response == 'T' ? 1 : 0; // convert the user input to the same values used throughout the program.
if(guess == coinToss)
//won..
else
//lost..
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there was something wrong with the condition I don't know how I didn't think of comparing the result to the user input.